# by factor sum with empty category

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi i'm running the same calculations for 98 country and need to take by(df$var,df$vactor,sum) occasionally. I create a segment factor variable with the cut function and need to calculate the sum by segment at a later point. This works fine, but I have countries where the top segment is empty and then I get a "NA" for the top segment in the sum. Is there a better way to avoid this, then just replacing the NAs with Zero in an additional command after? I want to keep the length of the about. 
MWE where i get an NA for factor level "C" in df2:

```
df1<-data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:3),4),
 factor=cut(rep(seq(1:3),4),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))
df2<-data.frame( val=rep(seq(1:4),3), 
factor=cut(rep(seq(1:4),3),breaks=c(1,2,3,4), include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_results=True , labels=LETTERS[1:3]))

by(df1$val,df1$factor,sum)
by(df2$val,df2$factor,sum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use droplevels function so it drop levels in your variable and print sum values grouped by factor

```
by(df1$val,droplevels(df1$factor),sum)
droplevels(df1$factor): A
[1] 12
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
droplevels(df1$factor): B
[1] 12
```

Or you can use ifelse condition

```
x <- by(df1$val,df1$factor,sum)
x <- ifelse(is.na(x),"0",x)
print(x)
df1$factor
   A    B    C 
"12" "12"  "0"
```

Can use as.numeric also

```
 by(df1$val,as.numeric(df1$factor),sum)

as.numeric(df1$factor): 1
[1] 12
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
as.numeric(df1$factor): 2
[1] 12
```

@ mike suggestion

```
by(df1$val,as.character(df1$factor),sum)

as.character(df1$factor): A
[1] 12
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
as.character(df1$factor): B
[1] 12
```

Comment: You could also use `as.character()`

Comment: Thx for the proposed solutions. The thing is I would like to always have the same length of vector, so that the NA is replaced by a 0. I edited my questions

Comment: The ifelse solution is basically just the additional command i proposed